# what is the type of filter that has values ones?

Tags: filters

I used the filter with values ones but i don't know what kind of type is?

`p=ones(1,L)` where `L` is the length of the filter

in this case what we can name the filter?

Comment: What is $p$? Pole locations, FIR filter coefficients or something else ?

Comment: type of filter but i don't know what kind of filter is?

Comment: @Hilmar  all the values is ones

Comment: "values": what do these values describe? Do they describe the filter zeros, or poles, or the filter coefficients? "Values" doesn't mean anything here!

Comment: @MarcusMüller values describe the filter coefficients

Comment: @AhmedAlShomi then you should accept A_A's answer.

Comment: @Hilmar yes all the values are ones

Answer (score 2):

This, on its own, would perform a summation operation of `L` elements of your input. If you modified it to `p = ones(1,L)./L`, then it would become a moving average (or in other words a low-pass) filter.

For more information please see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Ideal_and_real_filters) link.

Hope this helps

Comment: Another colloquial name for this sort of structure is a [boxcar filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function).

Comment: @JasonR Indeed it is, thank you. I think that the term originated in the United States.

Comment: you shouldn't be thanking but giving the "acceptance" checkmark by clicking on the grey checkmark left of the answer.